# Display RootViewController only when dismiss current ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I'm doing an ios project without using any story board and xibs.
Here I've come out one problem on presenting my `UIViewController`.

Here is the senario:

My RootViewController has 2 `UIButton's` that can present `ViewControllerA` and `ViewControllerB` when being pressed.

```
-(IBAction)btnAclicked:(id)sender{
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:ViewControllerA];
}
-(IBAction)btnBclicked:(id)sender{
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:ViewControllerB];
}
```

**And now inside `ViewControllerA` 
I have a button to `presentViewContollerB` as well, and I want only the `RootViewController` to be displayed when I dismiss `ViewContollerB`.**

In order to do this, I need to dismiss `ViewControllerA` first then `presentViewControllerB`. I know there is ways like using delegate to make it works, but I just want to know if there is any easier way to do this.

To be emphasised is that I want to use `presentViewController` only, not `pushViewController`. Thanks

Comment: If I am getting correctly than you want to dismiss `ViewControllerA` after presenting `ViewControllerB`, so that when you dismiss `ViewControllerB` it will show `RootViewController` instead of `ViewControllerA ` right?

Comment: yes exactly correct...

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer for your question,just do the following code,

in RootViewController.m

```
 - (IBAction)gotoViewA:(id)sender
 {
    ViewControllerA  *viewControllerA = [[ViewControllerA alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerA" bundle:nil];
    [self  presentViewController:viewControllerA animated:YES completion:nil];
 }

- (IBAction)gotoViewB:(id)sender
 {
    ViewControllerB  *viewControllerB = [[ViewControllerB alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerB" bundle:nil];
    [self  presentViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

in ViewControllerA.m

```
- (IBAction)actionBackFromA:(id)sender
 {
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

in  ViewControllerB.m

```
 - (IBAction)actionBackFromB:(id)sender
 {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

Comment: please read carefully on my question, this is not what I want, thanks

Comment: Wilson can you ask your question very clearly?. So that i will understand.

Comment: the Question is quite easy to understand, I want to present ViewControllerB in ViewControllerA, and then I want to show RootViewController after I dismiss ViewControllerB

Comment: Yeah i understand your question very clearly now.There is no way to to do this directly. If you present the view b from view a and dismiss the view b,it goes directly to view a only. No other go.

Answer (score 0):

Use the completion block of presentviewcontroller,viz will executed first

```
[self presentViewController:goTo_B animated:YES completion:^{
     //Dismiss A
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}];
```

If this does not work,write dismiss and just after it present your new controller

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];  
 [self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:goTo_B animated:YES completion:^{ }];
```

Comment: I tried this way alrdy and is not working, here is the log: Trying to dismiss the presentation controller while transitioning already. (<_UIFullscreenPresentationController: 0x7fbc735dc4e0>)
transitionViewForCurrentTransition is not set, presentation controller was dismissed during the presentation? (<_UIFullscreenPresentationController: 0x7fbc735dc4e0>)

Comment: are u implementing any custom transition ?

Comment: Not at all, this way will cause crash as the ViewController calling dismiss was ViewControllerA, but it was changed to ViewControllerB when the present is called, so the system cannot find the ViewController calling dismiss and its no longer executed

Comment: if ur app has root view controller then u can write this [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        
        [self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:goTo_B animated:YES completion:^{
           
            
        }];

Answer (score 0):

There's another way out, but i don't know whether its appropriate or not.

Create a property of type View Controller A in view controller B.
While presenting view controller B, assign an instance of View Controller A to the property in view Controller B.

```
[self presentViewController:goTo_B animated:YES completion:^{     
goTo_B.propertyOfViewControllerA = self;
}];
```

After that while dismissing view controller B you can do the either of the two:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[propertyOfViewControllerA dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]
```

or

```
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
 [propertyOfViewControllerA dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]
}];
```